# FSCalendar does not show all days within allotted view but needs to scroll

Tags: uicollectionviewcell, fscalendar

[image: Saturday is cut and user needs to scroll to the right to see Saturday]

I just added FSCalendar in Storyboard. I did not change anything via delegate methods. I just wanted to show all the days from Sunday to Saturday. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. My calendar was actually sitting on a view.  Then I was hiding/showing that view (and with it the calendar) on the tap of a button. I just added this:

```
fsCalendar.contentView.frame.size.width = calendarFoundation.frame.size.width - 10
        fsCalendar.layoutSubviews()
```

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the inner frame of CalenderView with respect to outer frame of the view. This type of calendar (Pods) has default (constant) space between columns and rows. Therefore to get the calendar fit into UIView need to adjust the constraints either programmatically or from storyboard. As per the following adjustment, considering this as sample, make it as per your convenience

calendar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: calendarView.frame.width-50, height: calendarView.frame.height)
layoutSubviews() OR layoutIfNeeded() // As per convenience

**OR**

calendar = FSCalendar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.calendarView.frame.width-50, height: self.calendarView.frame.height))
layoutSubviews() OR layoutIfNeeded() // As per convenience